# Visual Studio DB GDR2 - Can I deploy to a File without SysAdmin Privleges?

Tags: database, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008, datadude, visual-studio-dbpro

I have a Data Solution that has a Database Project and a Server Project.

I want to deploy to an SQL Script.  I don't want to have to have SysAdmin privileges on the SQL Server (SQL 2008).

Is there a way to do this?  I really don't want to set any settings or upload any server level stuff.  I only have the server project because my DB project needed it to compile.

I just want an SQL Script of the things that are not on the server for my database.

This is my current error message:

```
MyDB.dbschema(0,0)Error UNDEFINED00000: The user does not have permission to perform this action.
MyDB.dbschema(0,0)Error TSD01234: Failed to import target model MyDatabaseOnServer. Detailed message A fatal error occurred while the model was being imported.
   Done executing task "SqlDeployTask" -- FAILED.
  Done building target "DspDeploy" in project "MyDB.dbproj" -- FAILED.
```

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 1):

The permissions are allegedly spelled out [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833413.aspx), but I ran into this problem and couldn't for the life of me configure the correct permissions following these instructions. I ended up going the sysadmin permissions route.